# does postgresql 13 support the log rotate hot reload

Tags: postgresql

I changed the log config in server `postgres.conf` file like this:

```
log_filename = 'postgresql-%i.log'
```

then I execute this command in server side:

```
pg_ctl reload;
```

the new log file name seems did not generate, is it possible to hot reload this config and make effect? I also have run this command:

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

the log still look like this:

```
[root@k8smasterone log]# ls -alh
total 368M
drwx------  2 1000 1000 4.0K Jul 29 08:00 .
drwx------ 20 1000 1000 4.0K Jul 29 18:59 ..
-rw-------  1 1000 1000  81M Jul 28 08:00 postgresql-2022-07-27_143753.log
-rw-------  1 1000 1000  53M Jul 28 14:10 postgresql-2022-07-28_000000.log
-rw-------  1 1000 root 140M Jul 29 08:00 postgresql-2022-07-28_061040.log
-rw-------  1 1000 root  95M Jul 29 19:03 postgresql-2022-07-29_000000.log
```

did I have to restart the postgresql server?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  but he did set it in postgresql.conf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reloading the config files will cause PostgreSQL to start using the new pattern.  So the next time the log rotates, it will use that pattern.  But it doesn't cause a rotate to happen when it otherwise would not, so there will be no immediate visible evidence it is using a new pattern.  You would need to trigger a rotate separately (*after* doing the reload)

```
select pg_rotate_logfile();
```